# can't create independent variable using VectorAssembler in python AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

```
    from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
bag = ["age","total_purchase","account_manager","years","num_sites"]
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = bag , outputCol="features")
va_df = vectorAssembler.transfrom(spark_df)
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10752/4250017324.py in ----> 1 va_df = vectorAssembler.transfrom(spark_df)
```

AttributeError: 'VectorAssembler' object has no attribute 'transfrom'

Comment: Have you tried "transf**or**m"?

Comment: really ? I spent hours just for this, apparently I would have spent more if you hadn't told me. you are great, thank you

Comment: Aha - sometimes it just needs another pair of eyes :)